# Appending a string to the end of a text file for an existing file

Tags: excel, file-io, append, vba

I am new to vba script, I'm trying to append a string in an existing file.
But its replacing the code of the older file there are many ways in the web but couldn't make it out successfully.

thanks in advance for any help on this code

Code is:

```
Sub AddData()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim stream As TextStream
    Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\itscodes.txt", ForAppending)
    stream.Write ",sdfThis line uses the Write method53535."
    stream.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `CreateTextFile`, which creates a new text file, overwriting any file at the same path.

Use `OpenTextFile` instead.